# Strip PHP extension using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

in .htaccess file.

It works ok in that www.site.com/about shows the about.php page, but it still allows users to strictly specify .php, for e.g. www.site.com/about.php does not strip the .php.

Is it possible to do this, so even when they type the .php extension it strips it but still shows that page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add this rule before your current rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```